Is p→p a theorem in intuitionistic logic?
In 'normal' propositional logic, the formulae p→q and ¬p∨q are interchangeable. The rule of excluded middle, namely ¬p∨p, is replaced to p→p. Since intuitionistic logic rejects law of excluded middle, this gives people a kind of feeling that p→p is incorrect in intuitionistic logic, which is a bit surprising to me.
Of course this not a rigorous proof. For a formal proof, I expect something like showing p→p is not derivable from a set of axioms with modus ponens. Since I am not very familiar with intuitionistic logic myself, I cannot prove or disprove it on my own. Is it true?

The rough intuition is that disjunction is very strong in intuitionistic logic because it has to satisfy the disjunction property, whereas implication already satisfies enough metatheoretical properties in classical logic. This is why implications (weak) aren't generally equivalent to certain disjunctions (strong). The intuition with regards to implication is only rough, though; Peirce's law shows that classical and intuitionistic logic differ even on implication alone.

To be more specific, in intuitionistic logic, A → B does not entail ¬A ∨ B. Though the converse does hold.

Multiple answers give examples of proofs. It is worth knowing that working mathematicians take S and K along with modus ponens and this is enough to prove P → P. For usage in context, see Metamath's intuitionistic proof statement.

Appreciated for the comments and answers. All three answers are very helpful: one answered the question literally, one explains with the BHK interpretation, and the other one introduces methods to show the non-validity of certain intuitionistic propositions. Unfortunately, I can only accept only one answer, so I picked the one that helps the most.

As other answers say, P → P is indeed provable in intuitionistic logic.  But it’s worth unpicking the argument that led you to this question.  Essentially you argue: we think of P → Q as equivalent to (¬P)∨Q, and we know that (¬P)∨P isn’t supposed to be intuitionistically provable, so P → Q shouldn’t be either.  The mistake is in the first step: the equivalence between P → Q and (¬P)∨Q is very classical, not valid in intuitionistic logic, and so we shouldn’t expect it to tell us much about intuitionistic provability.
Proof systems like natural deduction (any of its many variants) make the situation much clearer than Hilbert-style systems, by separating the meanings of the different connectives.  The basic reading of P → Q is “if P holds, then Q holds”, while the reading of (¬P)∨Q is “either P fails, or Q holds”.  We can show intuitionistically that (¬P)∨Q entails P →  Q: we’re assuming either P fails or Q holds; now if we additionally assume P, we can’t be in the case where P fails, so we must be in the case where Q holds.  Conversely, you can show P → Q entails (¬P)∨Q by using LEM or RAA — suppose P → Q; now by LEM P either fails or holds, and in the latter case Q then holds, so in each case either P fails or Q holds.  (Formal natural-deduction derivations of these entailments are very close to these prose versions.) But with just intuitionistic logic, you can’t show that P → Q entails (¬P)∨Q.
How can we show this isn’t intuitionistically provable? The easiest way is probably topological models, if you’ve met topological spaces before.  Briefly, fix some space X; then you can interpret formulas as open subsets of X, with propositional atoms interpreted as any opens you choose, and the interpretation of other formulas defined by:

[⊤] ≔ X
[φ ∧ ψ] ≔ [φ] ∩ [ψ]
[⊥] ≔ ∅
[φ ∨ ψ] ≔ [φ] ∪ [ψ]
and (most interestingly) [φ → ψ] ≔ int([ψ] ∪ (X\[φ])), where “int(–)” is the topological interior of a subset of X.

This interpretation turns out to be sound for intuitionistic logic: if φ ⊢ ψ intuitionistically, then [φ] ≤ [ψ] (and this is fairly straightforward to prove; it amounts to checking all the rules/axioms are valid under this interpretation).  But for most spaces, this does not validate LEM, and doesn’t validate [P → Q] ≤ [(¬P)∨Q].  For instance, take X = ℝ, and [P], [Q] ≔ (0,∞).  Then [P → Q] = ℝ, but [(¬P) ∨ Q] = (–∞,0) ∪ (0,∞) = ℝ\{0}.  So this shows that P → Q ⊬ (¬P) ∨ Q, intuitionistically.  Another alternative is to take X as the Sierpinski space, and [P], [Q] each as the open singleton — less familiar than ℝ, but simpler in that it’s completely finite, and gives a 3-valued model of intuitionistic logic refuting LEM fails.

I'm not familiar with topological models (but can make sense of your answer up to the concept of "interior of a subset"). Could you list a good reference or text book (say, undergraduate level)?

@mudskipper: I’m afraid I’ve never found a good self-contained reference for this — all treatments I know are buried in larger books on other topics. The best I know is probably Sørensen–Urzyczyn, Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, Ch.2 (mostly independent of Ch.1), which gives topological semantics in §2.4 as an example of the more general Heyting algebra semantics. // For “interior”, see Wikipedia or any introduction to topology.

I'm not familiar with topological models. How did you define ¬P?

@qrsngky: View the formula ¬ P as defined as P →⊥ — this is not specific to topological models, it’s standard in many classical and almost all intuitionistic treatments of logic — and then following the interpretation of → and ⊥ I gave, it comes out interpreted as the interior of the complement of [P].  So for instance in ℝ, if [P] = (0,∞), then [¬ P] = (–∞,0).

I think your ≤ means ⊆, and ¬ϕ is an abbreviation of ϕ→⊥. Is it correct?

@fantasie: Yes and yes!

Yes it is.
You cannot derive LEM from it because the so-called Material implication equivalence does not hold in Intuitionistic logic.
The first two axioms in your list are enough to derive A → A:
(1) ⊢[A→((B→A)→A)]→[(A→(B→A))→(A→A)] --- Ax2
(2) ⊢A→((B→A)→A) --- Ax1
(3)
⊢(A→(B→A))→(A→A) --- from (1) and (2) by Modus Ponens
(4) ⊢A→(B→A) --- Ax1
(5) ⊢A→A --- from (3) and (4) by Modus Ponens.

In intuitionistic logic, the statement p -> q is best read as "From a proof of p we can obtain a proof of q". Thus, p -> p is trivially true.
On the other hand, p v q can be read as "We can identify a true case between p and q, and provide a proof for it.". This in particular means that to prove p v ¬p, we would actually need to determine the truth value of p.
